# простая реализация системы blockchain

Tags: php

Встречались ли вам статьи где с реальными примерами  был реализован blockchain ?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вначале стоит поискать в сети

Answer (score 2):

Это даже смешно звучит

[API](https://blockchain.info/ru/api)

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uqAwFI7lOU)